# C: How add nodes to a tree in a loop?

Tags: c, loops, tree, nodes

I made a tree structure that only has a root. Then it's up to the user to make nodes and either add them as children to the root or an other existing node. Here's how the structure looks:

```
#define MAXCHILDREN 5      //max children a node can have

typedef struct node{
    unsigned int id;
    struct node* parent;
    struct node* children[MAXCHILDREN];
}node;

typedef struct spantree{
    node root;
}spantree;
```

Now what I want to achieve is to make say 4 nodes and add them as children to the root. Here is what I have done which doesn't work properly:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        node newNode;
        newNode.id=i;
        addChild(&newNode, &Root);  
    }
```

That doesn't work as when I run

> showChildId(0, &root); //where the first number denotes first child, second child etc.
>
> showChildId(1, &root);
>
> etc

I get the same id which mean that there is only one child added. So how do I go on making 4 **different** nodes and adding them to a parent(root in this case) in a loop?

Comment: I see no error at that level of algorithm, can you provide implementation of others functions ?

Comment: @Alexis: No need. The error is contained in that code.

Comment: @Alexis I tryied to simplify it as much as I can. Here is a sample ready to run http://pastebin.com/290ABdmt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework to me so I'll try to offer guidance rather than a definitive answer.

In this loop:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    node newNode;   // <-- newNode is created on the stack here .
    newNode.id=i;
    addChild(&newNode, &Root);  
                    // <-- and is removed from the stack here.
}
```

`newNode` is created on the stack every iteration of the loop and it is only valid until the end of the iteration.

To make it live longer you need to allocate some memory for it on the heap. Have a look at `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Thanks loads! Well in fact it's much beyond the homework constraints but it was puzzling me. I was hoping to achieve this without using malloc() as then it gets much more complicated when I will need to free but thanks for the guidance!

Comment: If you **really** want to avoid malloc then it is *possible*, but difficult. For example you could create a large static array of a `node` (i.e. `static node allmynodes[500];`). Then when you need a new node you use one in that array. But you'd also need to keep track of which nodes in the array were being used and deal with the possibility of using all the nodes in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding temporary values to the child list:

```
node newNode;
```

This creates a valus on the stack that only exists until the following '}'. The next iteration will most likely re-use the same chunk of memory for the new object. You need to dynamically create the object rather than stack allocating it:

```
node *newNode = malloc sizeof (node);
newNode->id = i;
addChild (newNode, &Root);
```

You do need to make sure the nodes are freed correctly, otherwise you'll leak memory. The function that frees the node memory should recursively call itself for each child node.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid malloc but it seems it's impossible :/

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Alexis, I see nothing right here at this level of the algorithm, but I'm not sure if you're skipping details or confused.

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++){ // I think you mean 5 here -- or rather MAXCHILDREN.
        node newNode; // This is a temporary on the stack.
        newNode.id=i;
        addChild(&newNode, &Root);   // &newNode is a pointer to that temporary.
    }
```

So addChild gets a pointer to a temporary newNode each time. It will happen to be at the same address on the stack, so they'll all point to the same place.  So they'll all have the same ID. That stack location may have been overwritten by then though, so it may be some completely random value.

```
for (i=0; i<MAXCHILDREN; i++){
        node *newNode = new node(); // C++, or use malloc if you're stuck in C
        newNode->id=i;
        addChild(newNode, &Root);  
    }
```

Should get you closer to what you want to do.

Comment: The tag and question title both say the OP is using C, so it would have to be `malloc`/`free` not `new`/`delete`